# Deploy node project to Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Can I deploy my own node.js project to Firebase Cloud Functions? I know it already not possible with Firebase but now Firebase introduce this Cloud Functions. Does this mean I can deploy my node project (heavy business logic API) to Firebase?

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not the way it works.  You use Cloud Functions by writing individual functions and deploying them to respond to event that occur in your project.  The functions run in a node environment.  You don't deploy an entire node project.  Please see the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) and [sample code](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/) to find out what you can do.